# Integration with parameters in Matlab

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

I'd like to plot the dependence in Matlab
$$\displaystyle y\left( x \right) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{10} {\int\limits_0^{10} {\dfrac{{dz}}{{\displaystyle x + \int\limits_0^{100} {\dfrac{{dt}}{{{t^3} + {z^4}x + {n^4}}}} }}} }$$

but unfortunately I have difficulties when I try to perform the second integration over $z$ with the error "Supported classes are double and single".

Could you help me?
Thank you in a advance.

Update. I added the code.

```
function z1=self_energy
x=linspace(0,10,100);
for i=1:100
n=1:10;
R(i)=1./(x(i)+n.^4+quadgk(@(z)Gamma_0(z,n,x(i)),0,10));
y(i)=sum(R(i));
end
plot(x,y)
function y1=Gamma_0(z,n,x)
fun1= @(t,z,n,x) 1./(t.^3+z.^4.*x+n.^4);
y1=quadgk(@(t)fun1(t,z,n,x),0,100);
end
end
```

Comment: Your code does not match the expression you are trying to compute. The function [quadgk](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quadgk.html) is used to integrate a *scalar* function, but here you have a vector $n$. You are computing a sum on $100$ terms (the `R(i)`) but the expression show a sum on $10$ terms. There is a `n.^4` lying in the integrand in your code, not in the expression. Also, keep in mind that the function you pass to `quadgk` must be able to take a vector input. Last but not least, you should indent correctly your code, that would help you (and us) reading it.

Comment: Thank you for you response. If I forget for the short time that I need to make summation then why I can apply quadgk twice? In both cases I make integration of scalar functions.

Comment: Note that the `n` you pass to your functions is not an integer. It should. And it should be `i` I think.